# PHP Loop do action for each 10, 20, 30 etc

Tags: php, loops, conditional-statements

In php i have loop e.g.

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 1000; $i++) {
   if ($i = 10 || $i == 20 || $i == 30 || $i == 40 || $i == 50 || $i == 60) {
      echo $i;
   }
}
```

imagine i need to echo $i every `10,20,30,40,50,60,..970,980,990` there should be way to not write 100 conditions in `if` statement. Is there some logical way to see if `$i` increased by 10 then do something like:

```
if ($i == $i+10) {
   ...
}
```

P.S. if possible i dont want to introduce another variable to count i need to find solution with using only `$i`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try:

```
if ($i % 10 == 0)
```

That will trigger whenever your index is exactly divisible by 10.

Comment: Use === for strict type comparisons.

Comment: Well-spotted Samy - I think I'm due for another coffee.

Comment: One more question how is this % called i cannot find reference on php.net

Comment: It's the modulus operator - it returns the remainder when you do a division.

Answer (score 5):

rewrite your for loop to:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 1000; $i+=10) {
```

And I don't know whether it worked for you with commas like this (as in your initial post):

```
for ($i = 0, $i <= 1000, $i++) {
```

Comment: This assumes that he's simply printing.  But, I suspect there's other logic in there.  He just simplified the code for us.

Comment: actually, the question was about printing, so not sure if there is or isn't any other logic. Moreover, I don't know how it worked for the author for with commas, not semicolons

Comment: it will start printing from `0`

Comment: Fair enough.  And if the goal IS to simply produce output, then your method is, naturally, more efficient.

Comment: there was also many other lines like $arr[$i]... so this is not what i need

Comment: @NAVEED: yes, you're right :) But I think it's quite easy to fix that, if the author really needs to just output these values

Answer (score 1):

Skip extra looping:

```
for ($i = 10; $i <= 1000; $i=$i+10) {
  echo $i;
}
```

Or if you still want to loop every single digit between:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 1000; $i++) {   
  if( $i % 10 === 0 ) {
      echo $i;
  }  
}
```

[Test Here](http://codepad.org/PD8IzoYV)

Comment: '===' is a good habit.  Here it is clear that $i will be an integer.  But, in general, I like to force the type comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside your main loop.  '%', or 'mod', gives you the remainder of $i / 10.  If the remainder is '0', then you want to print.

```
if(0 === ($i % 10)) {
   echo $i;
}
```